# Singleton logger holding multiple references

Tags: java, design-patterns, logging, singleton, log4j2

I have a Singleton Logger using log4j2, which will be called from various Classes.
The format of the output is - **date INFO com.so.pg1 abc**

Say I have 4 Classes (pg1, pg2, pg3, pg4). I am currently using pg4 class which internally declares pg1, pg2, pg3.
All of them have a private logger field in them.

```
private static SingletonLog logger = SingletonLog.getInstance(pg4.class.getName());
```

And all their methods have *log.info()* in them and I set the logging level to *INFO*.
I need a way to make sure every time a pg1 calls a log.info("abc"),
The output should look like **date INFO com.so.pg1 abc**.
And pg2 calls a log.info("xyz") the output should look like **date INFO com.so.pg2 xyz**.
But right now all the logs have the same class name com.so.pg3 as shown below.

The various logger references should be handled by the SingletonLog class implementation and should be seamless for the calling class.

Please help me rectify this.

Sample code here:

```
public class pg4 {
  private static SingletonLog logger = SingletonLog.getInstance(pg4.class.getName());

  pg1 two = new pg1();
  pg2 two = new pg2();
  pg3 two = new pg3();

  public void methodA() {
    logger.setLevel(INFO);
    logger.info("efg");
    pg1.methodB();  //This too has SingletonLog field with p1.class.getName() as input.
    pg2.methodC();  // same as above
    pg3.methodD();  // same as above
  }
}

public class SingletonLog {
  private static Logger internalLog = null;
  private static SingletonLog uniqueInstance = null;

  public getInstance(String className) {
    if (uniqueInstance == null)
        uniqueInstance = new unique();
    internalLog = LogManager.getLogger(className);
    return uniqueInstance;
  }
}

Expected Output for this code:
<date> INFO com.so.pg4 efg
<date> INFO com.so.pg1 abc
<date> INFO com.so.pg2 xyz
<date> INFO com.so.pg3 mno

Actual Output: 
<date> INFO com.so.pg3 efg
<date> INFO com.so.pg3 abc
<date> INFO com.so.pg3 xyz
<date> INFO com.so.pg3 mno
```

Comment: I don't think the code you have posted even compiles, please consider updating it.

Comment: This is not the complete code. I posted it so that people can understand my statements better.

Comment: I understand that you haven't posted the complete code @deepng, and I think it's good that you choosed to do so. The line `private static logger logger = null;` looks like it will fail on compilation, because you haven't specified a type. If the code (in the context of the application) indeed compiles, consider follow the naming convetion for Java, because it will make it easier for other developers to help! [Class names uses CamelCase](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm)

Comment: Sure Jim. I will keep that in mind the next time I post something. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Singleton prevents you from getting the output you want.

The first time Singleton.getInstance("a.b.c") is called, a logger is created with FQCN (fully qualified class name) "a.b.c". This logger is cached, and next time Singleton.getInstance("x.y.z") is called, it will return the same (a.b.c) instance that was cached. The getInstance() method ignores the specified FQCN once a logger has been created and cached.

The solution is to not use the singleton.

Log4j already caches Loggers internally. If you call `LogManager.getLogger("a.b.c")` from some place, and again call `LogManager.getLogger("a.b.c")` from a different place, you will get the *same* Logger instance. However, if you call `LogManager.getLogger("x.y.z")` from yet another place, you will get a *different* Logger instance. This is the normal usage and I believe this gives you exactly what you want. It will result in the output you showed under "Expected Output".

Comment: Awesome. Did exactly what I wanted. Thanks Remko.